# jQuery chart keeps adding up when page accessed through jQuery Mobile menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having this strange problem on my jQuery mobile app.

I have a AJAX enabled menu and on each page there is a small circle chart.

From the menu when I click on a page, it will show 2 charts and again from the menu when I click on a different link the chart keeps adding up.

But when I refresh the page it come back to normal.

Im using a basic circle chart plugin.

Below is my JS code:

```
 $('.demo').percentcircle({

                animate: true,
                diameter: 100,
                guage: 2,
                coverBg: '#f4f8f9',
                bgColor: 'rgb(239, 239, 239)',
                fillColor: 'rgb(92, 187, 2900)',
                percentSize: '19px',
                percentWeight: 'normal'

            });
```

You can see a demo over here http://vidznet.com/debug/tabs.html You can use the menu to navigate to the other page.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: A quick workaround might be to empty the demo div before creating the chart:  $('.demo').empty().percentcircle({...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that every time the $('.demo').percentcircle() is activated, it renders a new div. The function is called again on link change, so it keeps adding more charts.

Try running the $('.demo').percentcircle() only once, for example by adding a class when it's initialized with `$('.demo).addClass('init')`

```
if (!$('.demo').hasClass('init')) {
  $('.demo').percentcircle({...})
  $('.demo).addClass('init')
}
```

Comment: i tried that code, but it still keeps on adding the chart

Comment: Did you try adding a console.log() just after the function, to make sure this is the location of the issue?

Comment: it says `(nothing to output)`

Comment: Did you forget to give the console.log a message? `console.log('test')`
Just check how many times it's called, if it increases each link switch then the problem is the repeated init of the percentcircle function.

Comment: Its called only one...i added this code `console.log('test')` and in the console view it shows `test` only once